# In Rails as I switch between plugins through routes at runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, dynamic, routes, runtime

In Rails as I switch (enable / disable / loading / unloading) between plugins through routes at runtime?

For loading a especific plugin i use in the file "config/application.rb":

```rb
module MyApp
    class Application < Rails::Application

        #when starting the server
        #the application only loads the plugin "default_app"

        config.plugins = [:default_app]

    end
end
```

But I need to load other plugins at runtime, for example, a plugin ":x" and a ":y"
and be able to switch between plugins as follows:

```rb
#execute before every request
ActionDispatch::Callbacks.before do

    #making a request to: localhost:3000/load_plugin/x/:controller/:action
    #should load:

    MyApp.Application.config.plugins = [:default_app,:x]

    #making a request to: localhost:3000/load_plugin/y/:controller/:action
    #should load:

    MyApp.Application.config.plugins = [:default_app,:y]

end
```

Any idea how I should do this?

---

**EDIT**

I cannot do this in startup, because the plugins must have the following structure:

- vendor/plugins/x/app/controllers/a_controller.rb
- vendor/plugins/y/app/controllers/a_controller.rb
- (many others)

each file must replace the other in accordance with the request.
this should be true too, for models and views and anothers files like the assets folder

Comment: What is your intention to do this? Why can't you load both plug-ins at startup?

Comment: No, because the :x plugin and :y plugin, have common controllers/models/views, they must be overrided between requests.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good answer, but have you tried mucking around with `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_once_paths`?

This is the variable that tells Rails what files to reload. As expected, its purpose is for development (change a file and see the change without having to restart the server) and, AFAIK, it's not meant to be used in production (reloading code on every request seems like a good shot in the foot). However, it seems to be exactly what you're looking for.